# PostgreSQL: Convert to timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have the following SQL Server Script to do in the PostgreSQL.

**SQL Server Script**:

```
convert(datetime,convert(varchar,JoinTiming,108))
```

**My Try**:

```
to_timestamp(to_char(JoinTiming,'HH24:MI:SS'))
```

**Error**:

```
ERROR:  function to_timestamp(text) does not exist
```

Comment: What is the type of `JoinTiming`?

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto, Its of type `datetime` in SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL has a "time" data type.

```
select current_timestamp::time(0)  -- or
select cast(current_timestamp as time(0))
```

```
now
time without time zone
--
06:51:58
```

In PostgreSQL, you can't cast time to timestamp.

Timestamps contain a date as well as a time--which date should PostgreSQL use? There's no way to know. So PostgreSQL simply doesn't allow that kind of cast.

You can *add* values of type "time" to dates and to timestamps. So expressions like these will work.

```
select date '2001-01-01'  + '13:43'::time(0)
select '2001-01-01'::date  + '13:43'::time(0)
select (current_timestamp + '13:43'::time(0))::timestamp(0)
```

Also, the standard SQL CAST() works like you'd expect.

```
select cast(current_timestamp as time(0))
```

Comment: @Meem: You're welcome. I edited my answer to remove trailing milliseconds, which more closely matches what SQL Server's `convert(varchar,...,108)` does.